# Unable to play an audio clip

Tags: java, audio

Currently I am working on a project. The project contains sounds, and I'm having trouble attempting to play them.

```
private void playSound(){
    try{
        AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(this.getClass().getResource("delta/client/gui/resources/sound/ClipOfSound.mp3"));
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioIn);
        clip.start();
    }catch(Exception err){
        err.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It gives me a NullPointerException. The path is correct, I've checked it multiple times. I don't know what the problem is.. and any help is much apprecitated.

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.media.sound.StandardMidiFileReader.getSequence(Unknown Source)
at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getSequence(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
at delta.client.gui.main.ZButton$Button.playSound(ZButton.java:84)
at delta.client.gui.main.ZButton$Button.mousePressed(ZButton.java:62)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Line 84:
AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(this.getClass().getResource("delta/client/gui/resources/sound/ClipOfSound.mp3"));

Comment: `this.getClass().getResource("delta/client/gui/resources/sound/ClipOfSound.mp3"` what returns this?

Comment: `NullPointerException` on which line?

Comment: It returns the object of the inner class.. or in this case "ZButton".

Comment: Is this statement `this.getClass().getResource("delta/client/gui/resources/sound/ClipOfSound.mp3` returning null?

Comment: It appears so, however, I don't know why. The file exists and the path is correct. I changed it to ZButton.class.getResource()... But it still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AudioInputStream is not compatible with MP3 type files.